# In how many cases can a matrix be singular, for rotation, projection or reflection matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, projection, singularity

I'm currently doing an old exam (linear algebra), my real one is in three days. There was a question in it and I wanted to make sure that my way of thinking is correct. The question is:

When one expresses the following maps as matrix; in how many cases are the matrices non-singular?

1. a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
2. an orthogonal projection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto a line,
3. an oblique projection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto a line,
4. the reflection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the origin.

My answer:

- A rotation matrix is non-singular since it is invertible.
- Now I know that all projection matrices except the identity matrix are singular. The identity matrix is an orthogonal projection since: $I^2 = I$ and $I^T = I$. This implies that an orthogonal projection can be non-singular in the case that the projection matrix is the identity matrix.
- A projection matrix $P$ is oblique $\iff$ $P^2 = P$ and $P \ne P^T$. I figured that, since the only matrix that is a projection and is non-singular is $I$, and since $I = I^T \implies \not\exists P : P^2 = P$ and $P^T \ne P$.
- A reflection is invertible and hence non-singular.

Which concludes that in three cases the matrix can be non-singular.

I'm very curious whether or not I'm missing something and I would appreciate if someone could point out is that is the case. When doing the homework problems I have never encountered a question like this before.
Thank you.

Edit: It is a multiple choice question where I can choose between 1,2,3,4 and 5 possibilities where a matrix can be non-singular. So I don't have to prove it, however, im curious if my way of thinking is correct. (Why there is a fifth option in the answer I don't know)

Comment: Rotations and reflections are invertible, projections onto proper subspaces are not. Whether the projection is orthogonal or not is irrelevant - a projection (onto a proper subspace) is not onto so can't be invertible. Honestly I don't really follow your reasoning, although it could be an English issue. And why do you say there are five options in the multiple choice but then only list four options?

Comment: @runway44, thanks for you response. It is not about the actual projection but the projection matrix, so for instance $I$ is a projection matrix but does have an inverse. 

Also, there are five options since there could be maybe more than 4 cases where one of those 4 matrices are non singular. I'll try to rephrase some parts of my question, my English is not the best. Thank you!

Comment: A transformation is invertible if and only if the matrix defining it is invertible (doesn't mater what coordinates there are), so the first sentence of your comment seems irrelevant. And I still don't get what the five choices are; you've listed four, so what's the fifth choice?

Comment: I've edited my question and explanation. Maybe it will be more clear now what my reasoning and the question are. Thanks!

Comment: From the wording of the question, it sounds like they meant "When one expresses the following maps as matrices, in how many of these cases are the matrices **necessarily** non-singular?" With this, I would say that only choices 1,4 are correct. It is not true that **every** orthogonal projection is non-singular, so 2 is not a valid choice.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

At option number 2 in the question, that ask if the matrix for an orthogonal projection in $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto a line is non-singular. Indeed, the identity matrix is a projection, however not onto a line. This rules out the case of the identity matrix and hence no such matrix can be invertible. Concluding that there are two cases in which the matrix is non-singular, namely, the rotation and the reflection.